# Is it possible to call methods in one JSP from another while using dynamic include?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to call in a JSP a method that is defined in another JSP that should be included dynamically (include page ) not statically (include file), but I get a jsp compilation error "method is undefined". It works fine when I use <%@include file=""%>.

The reason I need this is that our JSP ends up getting too big and we get this error: "The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit" (whence the need to include other jsps dynamically), therefore we're splitting some of its funcionality into smaller JSPs.

Foo.jsp

```
<%@page language="java"%>
<%!

public String getSomeID(String param) throws Exception {
    return "someId";
}

%>
```

Bar.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="Foo.jsp"></jsp:include>

String id = getSomeID(param);
```

I'm aware that the better option here is to use a preprocessing servlet. We'll probably do that. But, for now, I merely wish to know if it is possible to call methods from another jsp while including it dynamically.

Comment: Generally this would go into a `.jar` file that is common to the project.  Do you have some common jars?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the code from your **Foo.jsp** in **Bar.jsp** 
if you are doing that with **jsp:include**.

Both pages in that cases are compiled into independent servlets behind the scene. Let's call them **Foo_Servlet** and **Bar_Servlet**.

What actually happens in that case is the following: **Bar_Servlet** while handling the request passes control and original request to **Foo_Servlet**. 
Once **Foo_Servlet** completes the response of execution of **Foo_Servlet** (and not original jsp code) is combined with a response of **Bar_Servlet**.